# How to build a sentence with some words in c#

Tags: c#, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to build a sentence by using some data points in a model using **C#**.

For Example:

> I have a customer model with properties named `"Name"`, `"MobileNumber"`.

Now, if I am **updating customer mobile number**, I will be raising an event like `"CustomerMobileUpdated"`. So upon recognizing this event, I would like to construct a verbiage in the back end like `"John mobile number has been updated from 111111111 to 222222222 on 01/02/2018 at 14:25:32 by User1"` and log it into the database.

I already have a system where I was using templates to construct the sentence by transforming the templates at runtime, but I feel it more of a static way, can anyone suggest how can I do this dynamically and intelligently without templates.

Few more Events are like:

ArrangmentScheduled:
$2,000.00 PIF starting 2/20/18 
2 monthly payments of $1,900.00 
Promise (Check)

FollowupDateChanged:
Followup Date changed to 2/1/2018

PaymentDeclined:
$10.00 from 2/1/18 declined on 2/20/20118, Code: 12545856, Reference Number: 5984316548

CustomerDetailsUpdated:
John's name changed from John Watson to John Miller.

Comment: any effort/initiative  from your side

Comment: The Template are now you are hard code in the application inside Right?. You can try with templates are  moved in database and retrieve the template based on the functionality. @Manoj Nelluri

Comment: Even if I retrieve the template from the database, it is statically stored over there, right? I am looking to generate a sentence dynamically by adding all the prepositions, verbs etc to the properties.

Comment: I may have ideas for a hackish solution for you to eliminate/simplify the static templates by coding the nouns and verbs in your event names and doing some basic NLP on the event name to generate a full English sentence. However, the solution depends on what other events are you using. Can you share a few more examples of your events like "CustomerMobileUpdated" that you are using?

Comment: Few more Events are like: 

ArrangmentScheduled:
$2,000.00 PIF starting 2/20/18 
2 monthly payments of $1,900.00 
Promise (Check)

FollowupDateChanged:
Followup Date changed to 2/1/2018

PaymentDeclined:
$10.00 from 2/1/18 declined on 2/20/20118, Code: 12545856, Reference Number: 5984316548

CustomerDetailsUpdated:
John's name changed from John Watson to John Miller.

Answer (score -3):

Try something like this: `Var msg = Name + "mobile number has been updated from " + Old number + " to " New number + " on " DateTime.Now + " by " + Userid` 
If this isn't what you're looking for then I don't understand your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am looking to add the prepositions that you have used "to", "on", "by" dynamically